# my python3 threading prog didnt work with fifo-queue

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, queue

That's my code:

```
import threading
import queue

qq=queue.Queue(10)
def x11grab(n):
    print('haha')
    while True:
        a='abcd'+str(n)
        n+=1
        qq.put(a)
        print('put queue:',a)

def rtpsend():
    while True:
        s=qq.get()
        head=s[:4]
        body=s[4:]
        print('head',head)
        print('body',body)

t1=threading.Thread(target=x11grab,args=(1,))
t2=threading.Thread(target=rtpsend)
t1.start
t2.start
```

I wanna x11grab() function put string 'abcd1','abcd2'... into queue,and rtpsend() function get the string from queue, and display it. It's a demo, but it didn't work. I think your advice could be helpful.:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never start your threads! change

```
t1.start
t2.start
```

to

```
t1.start()
t2.start()
```